# How to move next and previous based on button click

Tags: php, mysql, button

I am connecting and displaying values from database using this function

```
function display_content($the_id)
{
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_ADBTAG WHERE bcv = $the_id");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo $row['content'];
    }
//mysql_close($con);
}
```

I commented the **mysql_close** line because I presume I won't be able to move next and previous if I close the db connection. Please correct me if I am wrong because I am new at php and mysql.

I am actually trying to use mysqli because on my other post someone said it's deprecated but my code is going haywire when I use mysqli so for now I want to finish my project using mysql and move to mysqli when I get the chance to review mysqli documentation.

Now back to the problem, The function above is called via form submit button. I actually have 3 buttons. Go, Prev, Next. Go button acts as the submit button which is getting the content OK.

My aim now is to be able to move previous and next from current row of the database using prev and next button.

Any idea how to do it?

And lastly, where should I properly call mysql_close() function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want a fixed list to move back/forward through you could move the `$result` variable to the session and use that to move through.

However if you want live data when clicking through this wouldn't work/

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to call mysql_close() because php do it for now. You can do it in this case because your mysql-connection will be created each time you call the script.

In you case, you need to read the ids of previous and next entries in the DB and set the paths of next and previous buttons to this ids.

Comment: actually I have the ids ready to move back and forth using `the_id - 1` . What I do not know is how to call it from prev and next button.

Comment: @CharlesWayne why can't you do it like this?

`<input type="button" onClick="window.location.href='myscript.php?the_id=<?=$the_id-1?>" value="prev"> <input type="button" onClick="window.location.href='myscript.php?the_id=<?=$the_id+1?>" value="next">`

and than get the id with $_GET['the_id'] ?

Comment: Can I use myscript.php on button click and still get the result on my main page?

Comment: just say, your main page is index.php, you can set the links of the buttons to index.php?the_id=... . on click you will be switched to the main page with this parameter and than get the id of your entry.

Answer (score 0):

Since what you want is to paginate the content (records) from your database table.
Then the best thing would be to use the SQL start and limit constructs like so.

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE .... LIMIT start_index, number_of_items
WHERE the values are described as below:
    start_index: The value from which to pull the records. The first record is 0
    number_of_items: The maximum number of records to SELECT. e.g. 10 (Note: Phpmyadmin uses 30)
```

Knowing this, you will have to keep track of the current start index in use so as to know how to pull the `NEXT` or `PREVIOUS` page

```
Example:
Lets assume that we want our start index variable name to be xs, we could code like so:
$start = (isset($_GET["xs"]) and intval($_GET["xs"]) >= 0)? intval($_GET["xs"]):0;
//the first time on the page -- set the default start index
$_SESSION["start_index"] = $start;
//save it anyhow you want to keep track of the current start index
$sql = "SELECT ..... LIMIT $start,25";
..... //stuff to pull your content
```

Please note that you it might be better to use `<a></a>` tags instead of `buttons` for the `NEXT` and `PREVIOUS` link.
I also have a small script that handles this pagination thing available [on github](https://github.com/emmanix2002/PHP-Utility-Scripts/blob/master/utilities/function.pagination.php)
Check out the [documentation wiki](https://github.com/emmanix2002/PHP-Utility-Scripts/wiki/Utilities-Pagination)
Hope this helps you

Comment: my where clause is always = to 1. Meaning it only captures 1 row and that is the current. If I am to apply the method you are asking. I need to limit it may 30 from current moving backwards and 30 from current moving forward. From looks of your code it assumes that my result is more than 1 and that it will limit to 25. will that work even if I am only getting 1 result from my where clause? Thanks

Comment: what shall I put in <a></a> to move next and previous? I read your script but it's seems out of my league. Can you tell me which part can make prev and next link. I only need 1 row display at a time. meaning 1 row per page. thanks

Answer (score 0):

use limit to make the pagination:

```
mysql> select * from actor limit 0,5;
+----------+------------+--------------+---------------------+
| actor_id | first_name | last_name    | last_update         |
+----------+------------+--------------+---------------------+
|        1 | PENELOPE   | GUINESS      | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|        2 | NICK       | WAHLBERG     | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|        3 | ED         | CHASE        | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|        4 | JENNIFER   | DAVIS        | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|        5 | JOHNNY     | LOLLOBRIGIDA | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
+----------+------------+--------------+---------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> select * from actor limit 5,5;
+----------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
| actor_id | first_name | last_name | last_update         |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
|        6 | BETTE      | NICHOLSON | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|        7 | GRACE      | MOSTEL    | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|        8 | MATTHEW    | JOHANSSON | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|        9 | JOE        | SWANK     | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|       10 | CHRISTIAN  | GABLE     | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from actor limit 10,5;
+----------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
| actor_id | first_name | last_name | last_update         |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
|       11 | ZERO       | CAGE      | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|       12 | KARL       | BERRY     | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|       13 | UMA        | WOOD      | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|       14 | VIVIEN     | BERGEN    | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|       15 | CUBA       | OLIVIER   | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

where the first value of limit is the start and the second is the number of result, in your code you have to give it the page number instead of the 'start' number.

EXAMPLE 2:

```
mysql> select * from bank;
+------+--------+------+
| id   | amount | bank |
+------+--------+------+
|    1 | 100000 |    1 |
|    2 | 256415 |    2 |
|    3 | 142535 |    1 |
|    1 | 214561 |    2 |
|    2 | 123456 |    1 |
|    1 | 987654 |    2 |
+------+--------+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from bank limit 0,2;
+------+--------+------+
| id   | amount | bank |
+------+--------+------+
|    1 | 100000 |    1 |
|    2 | 256415 |    2 |
+------+--------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from bank limit 2,2;
+------+--------+------+
| id   | amount | bank |
+------+--------+------+
|    3 | 142535 |    1 |
|    1 | 214561 |    2 |
+------+--------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from bank limit 4,2;
+------+--------+------+
| id   | amount | bank |
+------+--------+------+
|    2 | 123456 |    1 |
|    1 | 987654 |    2 |
+------+--------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: will that not slow down my result? I am sorry I forgot to mention. My table contains 31300+ rows. I use where clause to get only specific row and make it faster. My where clause however is very specific because I need to display one row per page only. I am looking at something that will offset from the current record that matches my where clause. If you can confirm that it will not slow down my result given that I have 31300+ rown, I will try it. Thanks

Comment: the 'limit' always return fast queries, you can try it, remember to use your 'where' condition and 'order by'

Comment: let's assume I am successful in querying with limit. How can I navigate from one row to another. I always need 1 rown display at a time on my page. Thanks

Comment: @CharlesWayne you have to pass the value to the query, if you button is next, your variable is $actual + 5 (5 are the next 5 result), if you click the prev button the varible will be $actual -5, so that value will be received by the query to make the next search of results

Comment: my problem is this. In my code above, $the_id is not a continous number. it is actually the verse id (bcv meaning book chapter verse). my field for the actual table id is just 'id'. user is searching for verse and that is whats get feed in the variable $the_id. If I use next ($the_id + 1) when the current is the last verse of everybook. The next command isnt working. is there a way for me to make 'id' as parameters while user is still searching for $the_id? thanks

Comment: just to add.. my table structure is this... id(int) bcv(int) content(text)

Comment: @CharlesWayne in my Code number is not the ID where to start, it's the position TO START.  Let me edit it to show you and find you another example